# Tomcat server taking very long time to load

Tags: tomcat, servlets, intellij-idea, tomcat8

I'm fairly junior with front end programming. I'm a bit comfortable with working with Javascript/react etc but I don't really know anything server side (i know OF tomcat/servers but nothing significant). The same is said for my team

I have a web application I'm trying to understand. For development, I'm using Intellij to run (what I think are two tomcat servers?) an application, and the UI for that application, both server side (I think this because I see two localhosts)

Long story short, running these takes a long time (both take +105 seconds). Even if I can save time by running both at the same time, I'd like to try and understand why it is taking so long.

Going through the console, it's all gibberish at my level, but going by the timer, I see two actions being done which account for about 70 seconds

```
2017-08-03 00:56:21 9556 [main] INFO o.s.b.c.e.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@6743e411: startup date [Thu Aug 03 00:56:21 SGT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-08-03 00:56:27 9556 [main] INFO  o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Overriding bean definition for bean 'dataSource' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari; factoryMethodName=dataSource; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat; factoryMethodName=dataSource; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]]
.
.
.
2017-08-03 00:56:45 9556 [main] INFO  o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
DmeInitializer.initialize Application initialized
2017-08-03 00:57:51 9556 [main] INFO  c.f.f.c.s.t.pools.RulesManager - Compiling processing rules for Compare 26
```

If it also matters, based on the log,

```
2017-08-03 00:56:29 9556 [main] INFO  o.a.catalina.core.StandardEngine - 
Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.4
```

Can anyone give any advice on how i can reduce the run time for these? It's quite significant since any change I make in the UI wont be reflected unless i restart the UI servlet

Another part of the problem is I'm not familiar with Gradle (some kind of project manager which seems to be relevant for servlet configuration) which makes things a bit more difficult. In intellij other than defining the workspace, and some custom configuration (via VM options), it looks like there is some sort of class being defined. I plan to find and look into that although I imagine it wont lead to any speed ups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Semi resolved my issue
I followed this link:
https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-application-live-reload-hot-swap-with
(had to alter the first step to do the same thing but with gradle i.e. add

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
```

to the gradle.build (the correct one, not any random one).

then after finishing the rest of the step, add this line to application.properties:

```
spring.thymeleaf.cache= false
```

THEN when running the tomcat servlets, don't just run them, you need to run them in debug mode

After doing all of the above, this works by:
when servlets are running in intellij
-make your UI code change
-save it (in my case i was using notepad++ not intellij
- go back to intellij (just bring the window into focus)
- then go back to browser and refresh the browser

now instead of waiting 100 seconds every time i make a change, i only need to wait 100 seconds once at the beginning, and that its